# Compilation error: missing return statement

Tags: java

```
class Employee
{
int emp_no;
String emp_name;
double emp_sal;

public Employee(int e_no,String e_name,double e_sal)
{
emp_no=e_no;
emp_name=e_name;
emp_sal=e_sal;
}

public double calBonus()
{
return (emp_sal/10);
}

public void display()
{
System.out.println("Employee No: "+this.emp_no);
System.out.println("Employee Name: "+this.emp_name);
System.out.println("Employee Gross Salary: "+ (emp_sal+calBonus()));
}

}

class Clerk extends Employee
{
String Grade;

public Clerk(int e_no,String e_name,double e_sal,String e_Grade)
{
super(e_no,e_name,e_sal); 
Grade=e_Grade;
this.set_Grade(e_Grade);
}
String set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
**this.Grade=e_Grade;
}
String get_Grade()
{
return this.Grade;
}**

public void display()
{
super.display();
System.out.println("Grade: " + this.Grade);
}

}

class PaySlip
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Employee c1;

c1=new Clerk(76,"Saman",12000.50,"Grade1");

c1.display();
}
}
```

**

Something is wrong in the Bolded lines.But I can not figure it out.When I compile this an error is displayed saying "missing return statement '}'.

**

Comment: sry. I edited the bold lines. can you make a rollback

Comment: Could you edit your question, select all code and click the code sample button¹ in the editor to make it more readable?

¹) The button with 101/010

Comment: btw don't use CamelCase for fields, start them with non capitalized letter.

Comment: The constructor fro Clerk assigns Grade value and then calls setter. You should choose one of above.

Answer (score 6):

```
String set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
    this.Grade=e_Grade;
}
```

should be

```
void set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
    this.Grade=e_Grade;
}
```

you have declared return type to `String` it should be `void` because you don't have return statement it is a setter.

Answer (score 1):

```
String set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
this.Grade=e_Grade;
}
```

You're declaring that `set_Grade` returns a `String`, but there's no `return` statement. Probably you want the method to "return" `void` instead:

```
void set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
this.Grade=e_Grade;
}
```

By the way, the usual way to name getters and setters in Java would be without the underscore: `setGrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature on set_Grade specifies that a String should be returned but you aren't returning anything.

Also please have a look through both http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html for the accepted ways of naming things and formatting code in java.

The more readable code is, the easier it is to fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
String set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
**this.Grade=e_Grade;
}
String get_Grade()
{
return this.Grade;
}**
```

You have a default method that should return a String.

```
public void set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
  this.Grade=e_Grade;
}
public String get_Grade()
{
   return this.Grade;
}
```

> Within an instance method or a
>   constructor, this is a reference to
>   the current object — the object whose
>   method or constructor is being called.
>   You can refer to any member of the
>   current object from within an instance
>   method or a constructor by using this

```
   private String grade;

   public void setGrade(String grade) {
     this.grade = grade
   }

   public String getGrade() {
     return this.grade; 
    }
```

You can also use this to set the generic parameter for method

```
   public <T> T doStaf(T t) {
      //method body
      return t;
   }

   public void doStaff2() {

      String s =  this.<String>doStaff("STRING");

   }
```

ps the formating does not work in the code block

Answer (score 0):

Number of things I would fix.

1. Change

   String set_Grade(String e_Grade)
   {
      this.Grade=e_Grade;
   }

To

```
public void set_Grade(String e_Grade)
{
 this.Grade=e_Grade; //also fix the variable name to start with lower case like grade.. followed by convention
}
```

2. Apply this in the following constructor to prevent ambiguity.

   public Employee(int e_no,String e_name,double e_sal)
   {

   this.emp_no=e_no;

   this.emp_name=e_name;

   this.emp_sal=e_sal;

   }

Answer (score 0):

The "set_Grade" method is not returning a "String" and therefore the compiler doesn't like it.

This type of method is known as a "setter" or "mutator" ( as opposed to a "getter" or "accessor"). Most setter methods do not return a value and therefore the return type should be "void". Therefore, replacing "String" with "void" will allow your code to compile.

On another note, Java coding conventions lay down best practice rules on how to name your methods. So your method should really be named:

void setGrade(....)

SP